# View [fontent.layouts.header] not found

Tags: laravel

View [fontent.layouts.header] not found. but there is a file in frontent folder in this there is a folder layouts and in this there is header file

Comment: Show us some relevant code! ex: `web.php` etc..

Answer (score 0):

It is clear that there is a spelling mistake you have did

I can see `fontent` instead of `frontent`

And please do some research before asking a question.